# Re-submitting the form after validation in JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have an issue with form validation in JavaScript.
I can't re-submit the form after validation by clicking the submit button again unless I reload the page. I want to be able to resubmit the form after refill the error shown fields without the need to refresh the page and form. Is there a way to resubmit the form by clicking the submit button without reload the page?

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const P_FirstName = document.getElementById("P_FirstName");
const P_LastName = document.getElementById("P_LastName");
const P_Email = document.getElementById("P_Email");
const P_PhoneNum = document.getElementById("P_PhoneNum");
const ParentID = document.getElementById("ParentID");
const Password = document.getElementById("Password");
// const cPassword = document.getElementById("c-password");

//Show Error Message
function showError(input, message) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = "input error";
  const small = formControl.querySelector("small");
  small.innerText = message;
}
//Show Success message
function showSuccess(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.classList.add("success");
}

// Get Field Name
function getFieldName(input) {
  return input.id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.id.slice(1);
}

// Condition Functions 

//1. Check Required fields
function checkRequired(inputArr) {
  inputArr.forEach(function(input) {
    if (input.value.trim() === "" || input.value === '') {
      showError(input, `الرجاء اكمال المعلومات`);
    } else {
      showSuccess(input);
    }
  });
}

//2. Check Input Lenght
function checkLenghth(input, min, max) {
  if (input.value.length < min) {
    showError(
      input,
      `${getFieldName(input)} must be at least ${min} characters `
    );
  } else if (input.value.length > max) {
    showError(
      input,
      `${getFieldName(input)} must be less than ${max} characters `
    );
  } else {
    showSuccess(input);
  }
}
// 2. Check First Name
function checkFirstName(input) {
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var ArabicLetters = /^([\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]|[\ufbd3-\ufd3f]|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]|[\ufd92-\ufdc7]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]|[\ufdf0-\ufdfd])*$/g;
  if (input.value.match(letters) || input.value.match(ArabicLetters)) {
    showSuccess(input);
  } else {
    showError(
      input,
      `الاسم الاول يجب ان يتضمن حروف فقط بلا أرقام  `
    );
  }
}
// 3. Check Last Name
function checkLastName(input) {
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var ArabicLetters = /^([\u0600-\u06ff]|[\u0750-\u077f]|[\ufb50-\ufbc1]|[\ufbd3-\ufd3f]|[\ufd50-\ufd8f]|[\ufd92-\ufdc7]|[\ufe70-\ufefc]|[\ufdf0-\ufdfd])*$/g;
  if (input.value.match(letters) || input.value.match(ArabicLetters)) {
    showSuccess(input);
  } else {
    showError(
      input,
      `الاسم الاخير يجب ان يتضمن حروف فقط بلا أرقام  `
    );
  }
}

// 3. Check E-mail Is Valid
function checkEmail(input) {
  var validRegex = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
  if (input.value.match(validRegex)) {
    showSuccess(input);
  } else {
    showError(input, "البريد الالكتروني المدخل غير صحيح");
  }
}

// 4. Check Phone Number
function checkPhoneNumber(input) {
  var Ph_regex = new RegExp(/^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/);
  if (input.value.match(Ph_regex)) {
    showSuccess(input);
  } else {
    showError(input, "رقم الهاتف المدخل غير صحيح");
  }
}

// 5. Check Username 
function checkUserName(input) {
  var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
  if (input.value.match(usernameRegex)) {
    showSuccess(input);
  } else {
    showError(input, " اسم المستخدم المدخل غير صحيح");
  }
}

function checkPassword(input) {
  var passw = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;
  if (input.value.match(passw)) {
    showSuccess(input);
  } else {
    showError(input, "يجب ان تحتوي كلمة المرور على احرف كبيرة وصغيرة ، ورقم و رمز واحد على الاقل");
  }
}


form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  checkRequired([P_FirstName, P_LastName, P_Email, P_PhoneNum, ParentID, Password]); //Done
  checkLenghth(Password, 8, 25);
  checkFirstName(P_FirstName); //Done
  checkLastName(P_LastName); //Done
  checkEmail(P_Email); //Mostly yes
  checkPhoneNumber(P_PhoneNum); // Done
  checkUserName(ParentID); // 
  checkPassword(Password);

});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="con">
    <h1> إنشاء حساب جديد</h1>
    <form action="" id="form" class="form">

      <div class="input" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
        <label for="P_FirstName">الاسم الاول</label>
        <input type="text" name="P_FirstName" id="P_FirstName" autocomplete="off" />
        <small>Error message</small>
      </div>
      <div class="input" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
        <label for="P_LastName">الاسم الاخير</label>
        <input type="text" name="P_LastName" id="P_LastName" autocomplete="off" />
        <small>Error message</small>
      </div>

      <div class="input" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center" lang="en">
        <label for="P_Email">البريد الالكتروني</label>
        <input type="text" name="P_Email" id="P_Email" placeholder="user@gmail.com" autocomplete="off" />
        <small>Error message</small>

      </div>

      <div class="input" lang="en" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
        <label for="P_PhoneNum">رقم الهاتف </label>
        <input type="text" name="P_PhoneNum" id="P_PhoneNum" placeholder="05xxxxxxxx" autocomplete="off" />
        <small>Error message</small>
      </div>

      <div class="input" lang="en" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
        <label for="ParentID">اسم المستخدم </label>
        <input type="text" name="ParentID" id="ParentID" autocomplete="off" />
        <small>Error message</small>
      </div>

      <div class="input" lang="en" style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center">
        <label for="Password">كلمة المرور </label>
        <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="********" />
        <small>Error message</small>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">إكمال</button>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` called there, will _always_ prevent you from submitting this form. You need to make _that_ dependent on whether your validation result actually says everything was okay or not.

Comment: From a UX point of view, this is a bad design. Instead of showing redundant "success" messages to a user in case he managed to fill in the input correctly, the form should just submit. Dont "force" the user to click submit twice. You should instead check for errors, in case there are any, prevent the submission and show them. Also think about, if you really  need 5 different functions to simply check for different regex matches. Check out the `pattern`- attribute for inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the build in form validation.

- I restructured the HTML. Removed the IDs, they are unnecessary in forms.
- The error messages is controlled by the JS and the CSS.
- Use of the pattern attribute for validating content (I didn't test the regular expressions).
- Use of the minlenght attribute for username.
- Use of required attribute for all input elements. Then form will only submit when all the requirements are ok.

There is a lot here, so I removed some of the fields in the form.

```js
const form = document.forms.form;

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('the form is submitted');
}, true);

form.addEventListener("invalid", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.parentElement.querySelector('small').classList.add('visible');
}, true);
```

```css
.form>label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

small {
  display: none;
}

small.visible {
  display: inline;
}

input:valid~small {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="con">
    <h1> إنشاء حساب جديد</h1>
    <form action="" name="form" class="form">
      <label>
        <span>الاسم الاول</span>
        <input type="text" name="P_FirstName" pattern="[a-zA-Z\u0600-\u06ff\u0750-\u077f\ufb50-\ufbc1\ufbd3-\ufd3f\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufe70-\ufefc\ufdf0-\ufdfd]+" autocomplete="off" required />
        <small>الرجاء اكمال المعلومات</small>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>اسم المستخدم </span>
        <input type="text" name="ParentID" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" minlength="5" autocomplete="off" required />
        <small>اسم المستخدم المدخل غير صحيح</small>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>كلمة المرور </span>
        <input type="password" name="Password" pattern="(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}" placeholder="********" required />
        <small>يجب ان تحتوي كلمة المرور على احرف كبيرة وصغيرة ، ورقم و رمز واحد على الاقل</small>
      </label>
      <button>إكمال</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```